# Class Template Static Member Initialized Twice

Tags: c++, class, templates, static, initialization

There is an issue with my **Instance** class in that I noticed a difference in behavior that stems from two methods of initializing a static member.

The class template **Instance** is keeping track of a unique count. The unique count is being used to keep track of the amount of derived classes for a specific type. It is also used to assign a unique id/index for derived classes.

The first is initialized as follows:

```
template<typename Derived, typename Key>
Key Instance<Derived, Key>::count_static_assign{ std::numeric_limits<Key>::min() };
```

The second is initialized as such:

```
template<typename Derived, typename Key>
Key Instance<Derived, Key>::count_default{ 0 };
```

Program's output

```
1 1
2 1
```

I expect the two values to be equal because they should both be incrementing. However `count_static_assign`, is giving the wrong output as it appears to reset and be equal to **1** twice. Thus, I would like to know why there is a difference in behavior between these two static variables.

Here are the files for the program that demonstrates the error.

Instance.h

```
#ifndef INSTANCE_H
#define INSTANCE_H

#include <cinttypes>
#include <limits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename Derived, typename Key = std::uint16_t>
class Instance {
public:
    using KeyType = Key;
    static KeyType count_static_assign;
    static KeyType count_default;
public:
    Instance() = default;
    virtual ~Instance() = default;

    virtual KeyType getInstance() const = 0;
protected:
    static KeyType generate() {
        count_static_assign++;
        count_default++;
        std::cout << count_default << ' ' << count_static_assign << '\n';
        return count_default;
    }
};

//doesn't behave as expected
template<typename Derived, typename Key>
Key Instance<Derived, Key>::count_static_assign{ std::numeric_limits<Key>::min() };

//behaves as expected
template<typename Derived, typename Key>
Key Instance<Derived, Key>::count_default{ 0 };

#endif
```

Base.h

```
#ifndef BASE_H
#define BASE_H

#include <cinttypes>
#include <typeindex>
#include <memory>
#include "Instance.h"

class Base : public Instance<Base>
{
public:
    Base(){}
    ~Base(){}
};

template<typename Derived>
class CRTPBase : public Base {
public:
    static const KeyType STATIC_TYPE;

    CRTPBase() {}

    virtual ~CRTPBase() {}

    virtual KeyType getInstance() const override {
        return STATIC_TYPE;
    }
};

template<typename Derived>
const typename CRTPBase<Derived>::KeyType CRTPBase<Derived>::STATIC_TYPE = CRTPBase<Derived>::generate();

#endif
```

Foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H
#define FOO_H

#include "Base.h"

struct Foo : public CRTPBase<Foo> {
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
};

#endif
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"

Foo::Foo()
{
}
Foo::~Foo()
{
}
```

Bar.h

```
#ifndef BAR_H
#define BAR_H

#include "Base.h"

struct Bar : public CRTPBase<Bar>
{
public:
    Bar();
    ~Bar();
};

#endif
```

Bar.cpp

```
#include "Bar.h"

Bar::Bar()
{
}
Bar::~Bar()
{
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"
#include "Bar.h"
int main() {
    Foo foo;
    Bar bar;
    std::cin.get();
}
```

If it matters, I am using Visual Studio 2017(Full Version-**191426433**) to compile. In addition, debug and release mode make no difference.

Comment: *If it matters, I am using Visual Studio to compile* -- What version of the compiler are you using?

Comment: Added the compiler version number value from _MSC_FULL_VER

Comment: No, just mention Visual Studio 2010, 2013, 2015, etc.

Comment: Understood, added the version at the end.

Comment: ok.  You do know that order of initialization of statics across modules is not defined?  Stick all of that code in one source file and test.  Do you get different results?

Comment: [For example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/285611f82486c365).

Comment: That example you posted behaves as expected, but I have a few questions. You mentioned how the order across modules isn't defined, but static variables are supposed to be initialized once, correct? If so, shouldn't the variable be incrementing off whatever value it was initialized with and not appearing to reset? Or is this all thrown out the window because it's undefined behavior? In  addition, is the counter that appears to work also undefined behavior? If so, what fix would you recommend?

Comment: Use the debugger.  Put a breakpoint on that line that increments the value.  How many times is the breakpoint hit?  Once the breakpoint is hit, look at the call stack to see what code initiated the calling sequence.

Comment: If you change `std::numeric_limits<Key>::min()` to `0` does it change the program output?

Comment: @M.M If you're referring to the original program, changing **std::numeric_limits<Key>::min()** to **0** changes the program's output to what I initially expected. What should be done if this code is indeed well-defined?

Comment: Report a compiler bug I guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code looks correct to me: `count_default` and `count_static_assign` have constant expressions as initializers, so they must be initialized before any dynamic initialization happens. `STATIC_TYPE` is dynamic initialization.

OP reports that changing `std::numeric_limits<Key>::min()` to `0` fixes the behaviour of the program, so I would conjecture that the compiler has a bug that it does not consider the `constexpr` function `std::numeric_limits<Key>::min()` to be a constant expression.

---

To work around this you could try some other way of coming up with a constant initializer for `count_static_assign`, e.g. a constexpr function that you write yourself, or a specialization for each type that you do use.